# Render is not loading the handlebars of requested page

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to load login.handlebars but this is not working.

```
router.get('/login', (req, res)=> {
  console.log('check we are in login section ');
  res.render('home/login');
});
```

in app.js engine is set

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'home'}));
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
```

Github link : https://github.com/shankarsingh482/login

Comment: What do You mean by 'not working'?

Comment: login page is not loading... i have updated the code on github ..please help me